# [Unity]How to draw a Ring Line in 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'd like to draw the trajectory of an object that is moving circularly, but I do not know how to do it.
Could you tell me a good way?

Comment: What do you mean by circularly? And what have you tried?

Comment: @maksymiuk I'm sorry for my bad English.I want to draw a line like a solar system arbit.

Comment: To actually just render lines (in a circle) in space, you could consider the GL library. But there's not enough info in your question right now to implement that, since we don't know how you're settings the forces acting on an object or moving it. Try including the movement code, and perhaps a screenshot of your scene so we have a better idea of how it's set up.

Comment: Maybe you could just use a trailRenderer on your object if you want to do it at runtime : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done a orbiting around something, but I am using Cos and Sin to generate static items around the object. 
If you use TrailRenderer with the use of MathF cos and sin to rotate around an object.

```
var y = amplitude * MathF.cos(Time.timeSinceLevelLoaded * speed) + currentPosY
var x = amplitude * MathF.sin(Time.timeSinceLevelLoaded * speed) + currentPosX
```

I've not watched it, but "Board to bits" on youtube has a tutorial on the matter. of [space orbiting for a planet playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5KbKbJ6Gf982bozKUYrX9C4qN_IQYTXZ).

Hope this is the right direction for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for a lot of response.
I found it works with below...

```
void drawLine()
{

    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[segments+1];
    for (int i = 0; i< segments; i++)
    {
        float angle = ((float)i / (float)segments) * 360 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        float x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
        float z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
        points[i] = new Vector3(x, 0f, z);
    }
    points[segments] = points[0];
    lr.positionCount = segments + 1;
    lr.SetPositions(points);
}
```